# Notification count on React native?

Tags: react-native

I have small react native code to render Notification like below:

```
notification.map((notification, index) => (
                  <TouchableWithoutFeedback key={index}>                          
                         <Text
                            style={
                              notification.isRead === true
                                ? styles.isRead
                                : styles.isNotRead
                            }>
                            {notification.title}
                          </Text>
                      ...
                  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

How can I count if `notification.isRead === false` and send result to another screen ?

Comment: wether you want to click the notification go to another screen?

Comment: So your requirement is "You want to count the total number of false before navigation to next screen"? Right

Comment: Yes. It is my requirements @Abdul Basit